Android Studio Custom View Coordinates are offset
I'm working on an app in Android Studio that lets the user visualize a family tree.
For the profiles of the family members, I created the custom view PersonCard:

public class PersonCard extends FrameLayout {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private LinearLayout textContainer;
    private View topAnchor, bottomAnchor, leftAnchor, rightAnchor;

    private int imageSize;

    public PersonCard(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    public PersonCard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public PersonCard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.person_card);

        int padding = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.person_card_padding);
        setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                    attrs,
                    R.styleable.PersonCard,
                    0, 0);

            try {
                imageSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PersonCard_imageSize, 0);
            } finally {
                a.recycle();
            }
        }

        imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                imageSize,
                imageSize
        );
        imageParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_avatar);

        textContainer = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams textContainerParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        textContainerParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP;
        textContainerParams.topMargin = imageSize + padding;
        textContainer.setLayoutParams(textContainerParams);
        textContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
            textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            ));
            textView.setText("Text " + (i + 1));
            textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.black));
            textView.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 8);
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);
            textContainer.addView(textView);
        }

        topAnchor = new View(getContext());
        bottomAnchor = new View(getContext());
        leftAnchor = new View(getContext());
        rightAnchor = new View(getContext());

        int anchorColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.tea_rose);
        int anchorSize = 10;

        topAnchor.setBackgroundColor(anchorColor);
        bottomAnchor.setBackgroundColor(anchorColor);
        leftAnchor.setBackgroundColor(anchorColor);
        rightAnchor.setBackgroundColor(anchorColor);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams topAnchorParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                anchorSize,
                anchorSize
        );
        topAnchorParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        topAnchorParams.topMargin = -padding;
        topAnchor.setLayoutParams(topAnchorParams);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams bottomAnchorParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                anchorSize,
                anchorSize
        );
        bottomAnchorParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        bottomAnchorParams.bottomMargin = -padding;
        bottomAnchor.setLayoutParams(bottomAnchorParams);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams leftAnchorParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                anchorSize,
                anchorSize
        );
        leftAnchorParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT;
        leftAnchorParams.leftMargin = -padding;
        leftAnchor.setLayoutParams(leftAnchorParams);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams rightAnchorParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                anchorSize,
                anchorSize
        );
        rightAnchorParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT;
        rightAnchorParams.rightMargin = -padding;
        rightAnchor.setLayoutParams(rightAnchorParams);

        addView(imageView);
        addView(textContainer);
        addView(topAnchor);
        addView(bottomAnchor);
        addView(leftAnchor);
        addView(rightAnchor);
    }

    public int[] getTopAnchorPosition() {
        int[] position = new int[2];
        topAnchor.getLocationOnScreen(position);
        return position;
    }

    public int[] getBottomAnchorPosition() {
        int[] position = new int[2];
        bottomAnchor.getLocationOnScreen(position);
        return position;
    }

    public int[] getLeftAnchorPosition() {
        int[] position = new int[2];
        leftAnchor.getLocationOnScreen(position);
        return position;
    }

    public int[] getRightAnchorPosition() {
        int[] position = new int[2];
        rightAnchor.getLocationOnScreen(position);
        return position;
    }
}


A PersonCard looks like this:

What's important are the rose spots on each side of the PersonCard, as I plan to connect different PersonCards, and my plan was to use these empty views (the rose spots) as "anchors" for each of the PersonCards to connect via another custom view.
In order to have something that connects to two PersonCards, I created the ConnectionLine view:
public class ConnectionLine extends View {
    private Paint paint;
    private float startX, startY, endX, endY;

    public ConnectionLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ConnectionLine(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black)); // Set the color to black
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }

    public void setPoints(float startX, float startY, float endX, float endY) {
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.endX = endX;
        this.endY = endY;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, paint);
    }
}


It's rather simple, and just allows me to draw a line from spot A to spot B.
Next up, I positioned two PersonCards and one ConnectionLine in my Fragment, just like this:

In my ConnectionsFragment.java, I have the following code:
public class ConnectionsFragment extends Fragment {

    private PersonCard personCard1, personCard2;
    private ConnectionLine connectionLine;

    public ConnectionsFragment() {
        
    }

    public static ConnectionsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ConnectionsFragment fragment = new ConnectionsFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connections, container, false);

        personCard1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.personCard1);
        personCard2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.personCard2);
        connectionLine = rootView.findViewById(R.id.connectionLine);

        personCard1.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                int[] startLocation = personCard1.getRightAnchorPosition();

                int[] endLocation = personCard2.getLeftAnchorPosition();

                connectionLine.setPoints(startLocation[0], startLocation[1], endLocation[0], endLocation[1]);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}


I'm trying to get the position of the rightanchor from personCard1 with  personCard1.getRightAnchorPosition(); in order to pass them as the start coordinates for my ConnectionLine. Same with the left anchor of personCard2, where I use personCard2.getLeftAnchorPosition(); in order to get the location of the left anchor.
In my logic, with these steps the ConnectionLine should successfully connect the two personCards. However, when I execute the app, this happens:
In my logic, with these steps the ConnectionLine should successfully connect the two personCards. However, when I execute the app, this happens:

As you can see, the ConnectionLine is nowhere near the anchor point where it should be.
I also tried to connect the other anchor points, but they also didn't exactly connect where I wanted, and I'm running out of ideas. From my perspective the ConnectionLine couldn't be wrong, as it just takes the coordinates I give it and connects to them. Which means that my coordinates have to be wrong in some way. Additionally, the x coordinate always seems to be correct, but the y coordinate is always off.
Does anyone have experience with this? Or maybe a solution?

Turns out you have to subtract the coordinates from the anchor you want with the coordinates of the parent view, as the view is always relative to its parent view. You could use something like this:
public int[] getAnchorPosition(View anchor, View parent) {
    int[] anchorPosition = new int[2];
    int[] parentPosition = new int[2];
    anchor.getLocationInWindow(anchorPosition);
    parent.getLocationInWindow(parentPosition);

    return new int[]{anchorPosition[0] - parentPosition[0] + anchor.getWidth() / 2,
            anchorPosition[1] - parentPosition[1] + anchor.getHeight() / 2};
}

And then call this method with the anchor you want to get the coordinates of:
public int[] getTopAnchorPosition(View parent) {
    return getAnchorPosition(topAnchor, parent);
}

